# for each loop for selected rows in sql server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I want to select a table records and for each row run a stored procedure that this stored procedure uses some parameters.
My table contains ProductId, ProductUrl and ShopId
and my stored procedure Updates another table with this fields.
In c# i can use variable and for each loop and in this loop call stored procedure but i want to run this action in sql query
some thing like :

```
items = (SELECT * From Tbl_Products);
foreach(var pr in items)
{
   SP_Update_Products(pr.ProductId,pr.ProductUrl,pr.ShopId);
}
```

Of Course this is not true and just i wanted to show my meaning

Comment: Generally, you don't want to use loops with databases. As a general rule, lots of small updates will be slower than one large update. It is fine if your program logic operates in a loop, but I wouldn't perform an update on each iteration of the loop. I would save the updates until after the loop completes, then perform one update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql